# Uploading Jpeg fails with this function

Tags: php, function

So this function works almost perfectly but it fails with jpeg, works fine with jpg I think because the file extension bit i am not sure.

Anyone can see where I have gone wrong? I am also thinking to get the file extension by reading backward to the dot to be sure the file does not have other dots. Some ideas about that would be welcome.

```
function watermark($OriginalFileUpload,$DestinationWaterMarkedFile) 
{

$OutPutFile = $DestinationWaterMarkedFile;
$imagesource = $OriginalFileUpload;

$File_Extention = explode(".", $imagesource); // this will fail if some file has two dots
$File_Extention = end($File_Extention);
$File_Extention = strtolower($File_Extention);
 
if($File_Extention == ".gif") $New_Image = @imagecreatefromgif($imagesource); 
if($File_Extention == ".jpg") $New_Image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagesource); 
if($File_Extention == ".png") $New_Image = @imagecreatefrompng($imagesource); 
if($File_Extention == ".jpeg") $New_Image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagesource); 


$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('Logo.png');

$wm_x = imagesx($watermark);
$wm_y = imagesy($watermark);
$img_x = imagesx($New_Image);
$img_y = imagesy($New_Image);

$wm_scale = 6; // 2 = 1/2

$wm_w = $img_x/$wm_scale;
$wm_aspect = $wm_y/$wm_x;
$wm_h = (int) ($wm_aspect * $wm_w);

$margin_scale = 6; // 2 = 1/2
$margen_right = $wm_w/$margin_scale;
$margen_bottom = $wm_h/$margin_scale;

$dst_x = $img_x - $wm_w - $margen_right;
$dst_y = $img_y - $wm_h - $margen_bottom;

imagecopyresized ($New_Image, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wm_w, $wm_h, $wm_x, $wm_y);

imagejpeg($New_Image,$OutPutFile,100,NULL); // writes the watermarked file to the Marked folder

imagedestroy($New_Image);

}
```

Comment: How you know it fails? Any errors?

Comment: Suggestion: get the filename via [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to avoid the `.` problem.